# Updating column value using query & join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to establish a date when a transaction actually occurred in my DB since the system used tracks by transaction ID and not a date. The following query is what I've attempted, which ran, but did not update any values:

```
UPDATE dbo.transactions
SET t.time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
CROSS JOIN eod_master e
WHERE(t.clinic=e.clinic) AND (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

I have tested the following query to make sure that the value I am looking for is correct without any issues:

```
SELECT t.tran_num, t.clinic, e.time_ran, t.date_entered, t.clinic
FROM transactions t
CROSS JOIN eod_master e
WHERE(t.clinic=e.clinic) AND (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

Since there weren't any errors I'm not sure why the values aren't being updated. I did run into an error with my `t.time_ran`throwing an error `The multi-part identifier "t.time_ran" could not be bound.` But I got around it by getting rid of the alias for that table when testing.

UPDATE:

Just to clarify how the tables are setup. I have 35 different `clinic` values and each of them have a `start_tran_num` and `end_tran_num` for each day of business. `time_ran` is the `datetime` of when the end of day was established. The start and end declarations won't overlap at the same clinic, IE: day one starts at 1, ends at 200, day 2 automatically starts at 201, etc.

[image]

Here is a mock-up example of what the data is like. I've attempted the following code after all the provided insight without any changes. There are no NULL values in the `eod_master.time_ran` column and currently all `transations.time_ran` are null so the query shouldn't be attempting to put in the same values that already exist.

```
UPDATE transactions
SET time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN eod_master e
ON e.clinic=t.clinic
WHERE (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

Comment: First you should hardly ever need `CROSS JOIN` and never against the base table of an UPDATE statement. Use an `INNER JOIN` instead. Second, add `AND t.time_ran != e.time_ran` to your test SELECT query.  Does it still return any rows?  If not, then your problem is that you are updating the rows, but with the same values they already had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just try using the Alias in the UPDATE statement, so:

```
UPDATE
  t
SET
  t.time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM
  transactions t
  INNER JOIN eod_master e ON
    t.clinic=e.clinic
WHERE
  t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num;
```

I've had similiar issues when UPDATING joins.

Answer (score 0):

A cross join (can) return multiple results for each row; you aren't going to be able to update to set it equal to more than 1 value, so you need to use a regular join, not a cross join. Given that you are doing this with a range, you may need to use a subquery to find a single transaction that matches, and update from that.